# Membership Renewals with 'Partner' relationship causing membership lapses/missing contribution

Tags: civicontribute, civimember, relationships

Contact A has an expired Membership which was granting Membership to Contact B through 'Partner of' relationship. Contact B renewed after Contact A's membership expired through an online contribution page, and the record showed the contribution, however their membership had the status of 'Expired'. Not knowing what to do, we deleted the relationship from Contact B to Contact A, and then re-added it. Now Contact B shows no contribution and no membership. What happened, and is there a way to fix this?

Ultimately what we want is either Contact A or B to be able to renew the 'joint' membership - does Civi support this?

CiviCRM 4.6.7 on Drupal 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Ultimately what we want is either Contact A or B to be able to renew the 'joint' membership - does Civi support this?" No it doesn't support this. Generally I think users work on assumption that reminders should only go to Contact A, andI would suggest preferably with a checksum to a renewal form that sets First/Last as read only to stop contact B clicking on the link in the email without checking who it was to, and hence avoid risk of having name overwritten

Comment: There are situations where this is happening even though we don't expressly advertise it as a possibility. We have a public facing renewal form. Sometimes two people live together, Contact A gets the email and contact B says, "Oh i'll go ahead and renew that" and then a situation like this occurs. Is there a way to prevent this on the public facing form?

Comment: the only way i can think of doing this would be to make the 'joint' membership actually belong to an organisation, and have both individuals be a 'current employer' and have a 'permissioned relationship'. that way either can renew the 'organisations' membership and both will then inherit the extension of 'end date'. i doubt it is what you are after. households does not yet offer the same option though it has often been discussed.

Comment: @petednz - fuzion  I'm getting a similar problem to that described by the author.  Do you happen to know whether 'households' yet offers the same or similar options as 'organisations' or whether anything else is in the pipeline?

Comment: hi peter - haven't heard of anyone doing the spade work to get this built. If you have skills you will find support on chat.civicrm.org. If you have funding then you could reach out to one of the Partners such as us - list is at https://civicrm.org/partners-contributors